# Stacked Bar Chart , spacing within each column (ggplot2)

Tags: ggplot2, bar-chart, fill, stacked-bar-chart

I have figured out how to make a stacked bar plot with my data, but now the figure makes it look like the number of structures was the same for each type of structure. I do not think this is accurate, and not sure why R is showing the same fill level for within each column of total structures. The different types of structures comprising the "total" are present in the data in varying quantities, so I'm not sure why this graph makes them all look even.

Here is my current code:

```
ggplot(Brass.ready, aes(x=Genus, y=Total))+
geom_col(aes(x=Genus, y=Total, fill=Type)) + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, vjust = 0.75)) + 
labs(title="Mycorrhizal Structures Across Genera", x ="Genus", y = "Total Fungal Structures")
```

[image: Stacked bar chart showing the even spacing of fill colors (within each column)]

Comment: can you use `dput()` to provide `Brass.ready`?

Answer (score 0):

Without the data I cannot be sure, but it looks like you haven't grouped your data. It appears to be filling based on the proportions of Type with the entire dataset (not by Genus).

Try:

```
ggplot(Brass.ready, aes(x=Genus, y=Total, group=Type))+
geom_col(aes(x=Genus, y=Total, fill=Type)) + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, vjust = 0.75)) + 
labs(title="Mycorrhizal Structures Across Genera", x ="Genus", y = "Total Fungal Structures")
```